# 301 redirect using htaccess for blog pages and all other pages

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect an old website to a new website. I see the old site as two parts. The blog articles and everything else. I would like the blog articles to be redirected to their new locations on the website, while keeping the same URL (more or less). I would like everything else to redirect to the new site's home page.

Requirements:

1. All blog posts should redirect to their same URL (without the `/blog` part) but on the new domain
2. All non-blog pages should redirect to a single new page

Example:

- `oldsite.com/` --> `www.newsite.com`
- `www.oldsite.com/register` --> `www.newsite.com`
- `www.oldsite.com/pictures/cats` --> `www.newsite.com`
- `www.oldsite.com/blog` --> `blog.newsite.com`
- `www.oldsite.com/blog/cool-cats` --> `blog.newsite.com/cool-cats`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume different physical servers?

At the top of your .htaccess file on the old site, try the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(blog)(/.*)? http://$1.newsite.com$2 [R=302,L]
RewriteRule .* http://www.newsite.com/ [R=302,L]
```

This first redirects the "blog" URLs then redirects everything else. The order is important.

Change the `302` (temporary) redirect to a `301` (permanent) when you are sure it's working OK. (302 redirects won't be cached by the browser - in case of an error.)

However, I would recommend not redirecting multiple pages to a single home page on the new site if you can help it. This is generally a bad experience for users and Google is likely to treat it as a soft-404 and ignore it anyway.

Comment: Yes.. Old and new sites are on two separate servers.. Would you recommend linking all the "other" pages to the respective locations on the new site? If so, for how long? Also, being that the order is important, would I do something like `Redirect 302 /contact http://www.newsite/contact-us` above the rules you suggested?

Comment: Yes, you should link to the corresponding page on the new site... for as long as possible (ideally forever, depending on how well linked the old pages are). If you are doing specific redirects then yes, these will need to come first. However, you must not mix mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule`) and mod_alias (`Redirect`) redirects - different modules execute at different times so you can get unexpected conflicts. `RewriteRule ^contact$ http://www.newsite/contact-us [R=301,L]`.

Comment: Thanks for the insight and the help! Got it all wired up and working :)

Answer (score 1):

Put the following code @ oldsite , main directory, .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !^blog ($|/) http://www.newsite.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# above line will redirect entire site to new site and exclude blog directory.
```

Then ,put the following code @ the oldsite.com/blog/ directory .htaccess file  :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.blog.newsite.com/$1  [L,R=301]

# above line will redirect all requested url for oldsite.com/blog/ directory
# to blog.newsite/ with same extensions and if you remove $1 it will
# be redirected to index @ blog.newsite.com
```

If there are some blog/SubDirectories/ , check if there are no .htaccess in them , or they existing but has nothing , so no problem but if they have some rules ,Make sure that it is adapted to not effect /blog/ directory .htaccess rules

Comment: I may have been a bit vague about this but the old site is a wordpress site. I am unaware of a `blog` directory that would contain a .htaccess file

Comment: ok , do you have access to .htaccess in main directory only ?